# Finding all matching options in a select by attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML select control with several options. Each option has an attribute named 'linkid'. Example,

```
"<option linkid = '100' title = 'some title 1' value='1'>some value 1</option>"
"<option linkid = '100' title = 'some title 2' value='2'>some value 2</option>"
```

Now, I need to find all matching options by attribute 'linkid'.

I tried the following code and it did not work...

```
var matchingOptions = myselectcontrol.find('[linkid==100]');

var matchingOptions = myselectcontrol.find(':100');
```

The above code results in syntax error. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to find matching options by attribute value?

Thanks,
Vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so very close, try:

```
var matchingOptions = myselectcontrol.find('[linkid=100]');
```

Though it's worth adding that custom attributes, under HTML 4.x, are invalid; under HTML 5 there's the (valid) `data-*` attributes to hold custom data, which would still be invalid (albeit still functional) under HTML 4.x, but would validate under HTML 5.

Should you consider that a change worth making, your code would become:

```
<option data-linkid = '100' title = 'some title 1' value='1'>some value 1</option>
```

And

```
var matchingOptions = myselectcontrol.find('[data-linkid=100]');
```

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jQuery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Thank you. Able to get the expected result now. Thanks for the suggestions as well. I will make changes accordingly.